# Invoking class method from the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

I am trying to add webapi (owin.selfhosting) support to existing C# console app and I have problem with callbacks from the controller.  Essentially I need to call a function as a reaction to the  http request. <strike>I think it's possible with delegates/events, but so far no success</strike>.

## Update:

Using static event seems to work, I used a standard pattern as described in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0) and adding a static keyword before event declaration. But mixing static delegate with non static subscriber probably is not the best practice.

Code sample :

```
//appcontroller.cs
  public class AppController : ApiController
  {  public delegate void EventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
     public static  event EventHandler EventRecived;

     protected virtual void OnEventRecived(string arg)
     {
         if( EventRecived != null)
         {
            EventRecived(this, arg);
         }
     }

     [Route("api/{arg}")]
     public void GetFoo(string arg)
     {
        /*   
         *   
         */
         OnEventRecived(); 

      }
  }

//program.cs 
 class Program
 { static void Main(string[] args)
   {  WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress); 
      SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
      AppController.EventHandler+=obj.OnRecivedEvent;

      while (true)
      {  //do work
      }
    }
  }

  class SomeClass
  {  public SomeClass() {}
     public void OnRecivedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {  
        Foo(e); 
     }
     public void Foo(string arg)
     {
       //do something
       Console.WriteLine("request of "+arg);
     }
  }
```

Example for http get request to http://localhost:8080/api/holy_grail

```
  Console output >>request of holy_grail
```

Comment: Register the instance with your DI container and inject it in the controller's constructor.

Comment: That `static` business looks nasty to me. Check the comments above You can inject an instance of `SomeClass` into the constructor of `AppController` so the controller has the required reference (to `SomeClass`). There are loads of articles/posts about this.